# WP_User_Query search with multiple search queries

Tags: search, wp-user-query

Is it possible to perform a `WP_User_Query` with multiple search queries? Something like:

```
$args = array (
    'search'    => '*example.com OR *abc.com',
    'search_columns' => array( 'user_email' )
);
```

or

```
$args = array (
    'search' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'search_columns'    => 'user_email',
                'search'            => '*example.com',
            ),
            array(
                'search_columns'    => 'user_email',
                'search'            => '*abc.com',
            )
        )
    );
```

then perform query:

```
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

which would return users who's email domain are @example.com **OR** @abc.com.

Comment: A possible solution would be to create two separate queries which return just the user IDs and then combine these into a single array which is then fed in to a third query which `include`s only these IDs.

Comment: Have you tried it before posting the question?

Comment: @Dan Yes, the first method returns no results (tries to explicitly match the search string I think) and the second method returns all users.

Comment: You can't because `search` parameter accepts a string only. You should try SQL queries instead.

Comment: @mistertaylor you seem to answer your own question there :) run multiple queries and combine.

Comment: I know this question is 5 years old now but it's still relevant in 2021. I have this same exact question and running multiple queries and combining them just leads to slower performance. Any updates on this is appreciated.